# Vue doesn't render second component if the previous self-terminates

Tags: typescript, vue.js, parceljs

In my root component, `App.vue`, I have the following template code:

```
<template>
<div class="app-wrapper">
    <Header></Header>
    <Panel></Panel>
    <Showcase/>
    <Modal/>
    <Footer/>
</div>
</template>
```

I was just trying to mock-up an app I'm building, so the parts aren't nested and don't contain anything meaningful.

Each of those Vue Components contains the following in their `.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="panel-wrapper">Panel</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Panel"
});
</script>


<style lang="scss">
.panel-wrapper {
  background: orange;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
</style>
```

and this is the same for `Header`, `Showcase`, `Modal` and `Footer`.

**For some odd reason, with the above code, only the Header, Panel, and Showcase components render. If I change `<Showcase/>` to `<Showcase></Showcase>` then the Modal also renders.**

Shouldn't it render regardless of whether or not the component self terminates its JSX?

I'm new to Vue and set up the project myself with TS, and Parcel, but I don't think know if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with **Parcel** bundler. Parcel's [posthtml](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml) as an HTML parser which break with custom self-closing HTML tags.

As a temporary solution, you must tell bundler to explicitly recognize self-closing custom elements. Add the following config to your package.json:

```
"posthtml": {
    "recognizeSelfClosing": true
}
```

This issue is being tracked here on these threads:
[issue-1](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1363) and [issue-2](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2065).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing here is to quote the official vue style guide :

> Components with no content should be self-closing in [single-file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), string templates, and [JSX](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX) - but never in DOM templates.

You can find the full documentation here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended

> Unfortunately, HTML doesn’t allow custom elements to be self-closing - only [official “void” elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements). That’s why the strategy is only possible when Vue’s template compiler can reach the template before the DOM, then serve the DOM spec-compliant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Vue templates need to be a valid HTML. The self closing tags are of XHTML syntax and which are now outdated. You can follow the style guide of Vue documentation  [Official Style Guide Vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended)

for more information on valid tags in HTML please see  [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)